# Workstation switches to standby when power settings are set to never

Tags: power-management

We have several computers in our office that switch to standby even though the power settings are set so that it never goes to standby.

All our systems run XP Pro and we have several hardware configurations. The problem is not platform specific. Group policy also is set to never allow for systems to go to sleep, and the domain controller runs Server 03 R2.

With the systems in standby we cannot run several updates on them.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is there any unusual hardware or software element these platforms have in common?

Comment: Nothing I can think of. They are mostly Pentium IV with 80GB PATA drives and on board everything else.

Answer (score 1):

I would check sleep, hibernate, standby, turn off hard disk, etc. to see if they are *all* set to never.

Comment: All are set for Never. Only the monitors are set for 20 minutes.